# Change JVM params for Solr

Tags: docker, solr, garbage-collection, jvm, environment-variables

How do I specify another type of garbage collector for a dockerized Solr7?
My docker startup command is as follows:

```
docker run -d --restart always --name solrcloud \
-p 8983:8983 --net host myrepo/my-fusion-solr-image:latest \
bin/solr -c -f -a -javaagent:/opt/newrelic/newrelic.jar \
-Dnewrelic.environment=dev -Ddisable.configEdit=true \
-z dev-fusion-zk.aws.myhost.net:2181/dev-fusion -m 30g
```

I'm trying to follow this article: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ShawnHeisey
Where exactly should I specify `-XX:+UseG1GC` ?

Comment: `-e JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+UseG1GC'` may do

Comment: tried that, to no avail

Comment: How about `-XX:+UseG1GC` right before `-javaagent`, which is a JVM argument as well?

Comment: results in "conflicting collector settings" message at startup and app not being able to start. I figured the answer, will post shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dockerfile for Solr image, add following step:

```
# Use G1GC garbage collector
# https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ShawnHeisey
RUN sed -i -e 's/^#GC_TUNE.*/GC_TUNE=" \
-XX:+UseG1GC \
-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem \
-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled \
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8m \
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=250 \
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=75 \
-XX:+UseLargePages \
-XX:+AggressiveOpts \
"/' /opt/solr/solr-$SOLR_VERSION/bin/solr.in.sh
```

Solr 7.2.1 has this file `bin/solr.in.sh` that looks like it was added specifically to override some configs in `bin/solr`. There in `bin/solr.in.sh` is a commented out line starting with `#GC_TUNE=`. If we uncomment this line, it will override `GC_TUNE` variable in `bin/solr`.

`sed` command in the snippet above replaces that line with desired settings. Note that `sed` can act differently in different environments and may require some modifications to work for your case. Please test it before plugging it into your dockerfile. Above snippet works for centos.